# Convert current milliSecond to time format using C

Tags: c, timestamp, epoch, milliseconds

i need to convet current time in milliseconds to human readable time format. I have following code

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>

int Cnvrt_To_Time_Frmt(char *Epochval)
{
    unsigned long epoch = 0;
    time_t tt = 0;
    char timestamp[64],usec_buf[20];
    if (!sscanf(Epochval, "%lu", &epoch))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    tt = epoch;

    strftime(timestamp, 64, "%c", localtime(&tt));
    printf("%s\n",timestamp);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    uint64_t Epoch_time=1468496250207;
    char str_ms[256];
    sprintf(str_ms, "%llu", (Epoch_time/1000));
    Cnvrt_To_Time_Frmt(str_ms);

}
```

It produce result : *Thu Jul 14 17:07:30 2016*.

But i need to print result with milli seconds. like *Thu Jul 14 17:07:30:40 2016*.(17 hour,07 minute, 30 second, 40 milliSecond)

How it will be possible?

Comment: C or C++? Not the same...

Comment: in C code. i compile with gcc command

Answer (score 2):

Type `time_t` by [its definition](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time_t/) doesn't represent time with milliseconds resolution, function `localtime` returns pointer to [`struct tm`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/) which does not include milliseconds, [`function strftime`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/) is not designed to produce strings with milliseconds.

If you need time with milliseconds you can use [`timeb` stucture](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/systimeb.h.html) with its associated [`ftime` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/ftime.html) if those are supported by your tool-chain.

Comment: Note that definition is a generality concerning seconds, not a C specification.  `time_t` may provide sub-second info.  Still `time_t` as an integer second count is common.

Answer (score 1):

Use this as format string:

```
strftime(timestamp, 64, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S.XXX %Y", localtime(&tt));
```

The `XXX` will be copied as-is into the time string.
Then in `main`, you can overwrite the `X`s with the millisecond count.

```
sprintf(&timestamp[20], "%03u", (unsigned)Epoch_time%1000);
timestamp[23] = ' '; // restore the NUL to space again
```

After that, refactor your code so the divisions and remainder operations are done inside `Cnvrt_To_Time_Frmt`. You could use this as prototype:

```
int msecs_tostr(char *buffer, const char *msecs_since_epoch);
```

Answer (score 0):

*I don't have 50 reps yet so I can't comment so I will write my suggestion as an answer here.*

You can use the other guys suggestions they are pretty good or you can make your own struct and a function that converts the mili seconds into time , by using basic math functions.

Make a struct that contains dayOfWeek , month , dayOfMonth , hour, minute, second , milliSecond , year.
Make a convertFunction that will receive a value of milliSeconds that need to be converted to your struct format.
Maybe its not the best way to do it , but if you don't find a way of using existing libraries , make your own .

Answer (score 0):

> ...  need to print result with milli seconds. ... How it will be possible?

Take it step by step

```
uint64_t Epoch_time=1468496250207;

// Break time into a whole number of seconds and ms fraction
time_t t_unix = Epoch_time/1000;
unsigned t_ms = Epoch_time%1000;

// Convert to YMD HMS structure
struct tm tm = *localtime(&t_unix);

// Form left portion of string
char left[64];
strftime(left, sizeof left, "%a %b %d %H:%M", &tm);

// Form right portion of string
char right[20];
strftime(right, sizeof right, "%Y", &tm);

// Put together with ms
char timestamp[64];
snprintf(timestamp, sizeof timestamp, "%s:%u %s", left, t_ms, right);

// Thu Jul 14 17:07:30:40 2016
// Print as needed
puts(timestamp);
```

Robust code would add error checking with each function's return value.

---

[edit] 
Evidently OP's time stamp's last 3 digits are a fraction / 512.

```
unsigned t_fraction = Epoch_time%1000;
...
snprintf(timestamp, sizeof timestamp, "%s:%02u %s", left, t_fraction*100/512, right);
```

Comment: i got error when compile this code "test.c:31:38: error: expected ‘)’ before string constant
 snprintf(timestamp, sizeof timestamp "%s:%u %s", left, t_ms, right);
                                      ^
test.c:31:1: error: too few arguments to function ‘snprintf’
 snprintf(timestamp, sizeof timestamp "%s:%u %s", left, t_ms, right); "

Comment: @Abdul Manaf Missing `,` added.

Comment: thanks chux, But i got result "Thu Jul 14 17:07:207 2016".

Comment: @Abdul Manaf Modified to cope with fraction.

Answer (score 0):

This example program will both retrieve the current timestamp from they system OS, and print it out in human readable format.  It is similar to @user:2410359 answer, but a little more concise.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

/* 
 * timestamp - read and print the current timestamp
 * Wade Ryan 2020-09-27
 * compile using: g++ timestamp.cpp -o timestamp
 */ 

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char   timestamp[24];
    struct timeval currentTime;
    struct tm      ts;

    gettimeofday(&currentTime, NULL);

    long long epoch  =  (unsigned long long)(currentTime.tv_sec) * 1000 +
                        (unsigned long long)(currentTime.tv_usec) / 1000;
        
    strftime(timestamp, sizeof(timestamp), "%F %T", localtime(&currentTime.tv_sec));

    printf("epoch %lld ms :: %s.%03ld\n", epoch, timestamp, currentTime.tv_usec/1000);

}
```

Example output:

```
epoch 1601259041504 ms :: 2020-09-27 21:10:41.504
```